# How to draw rule from left text edge to right paper edge without overfull?

Tags: rules, width, layout

I'm currently using the following instruction to draw a horizontal rule from the left edge of the text body to the right edge of the paper:

```
\rule{\paperwidth}{2pt}
```

This works, but it results in an overfull warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (232.295pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--13
```

The proper way to do this is probably to calculate the actual length, but I don't know how to do this. I read about an `\addtolength` instruction but am not sure what I can add together. Can someone advise?

Comment: For oneside you can use `\noindent\rlap{\rule{\dimexpr \paperwidth - 1in - \oddsidemargin}{2pt}}`

Comment: Use a TikZ picture.

Comment: @DũngVũ Seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\noindent\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule{\paperwidth}{2pt}}\par
Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `tikz` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (\paperwidth, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under `onside` (the default) mode in `article`, the length from the left side of the text block to the right side of the page is given by

```
\paperwidth - \oddsidemargin - 1in - \hoffset
%             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
%                       left margin
```

To see this, load the [`layout` package](//ctan.org/pkg/layout) and issue `\layout` to see what lengths are at work:

[image]

However, as long as the length is longer than the above length, it'll stretch all the way to the right side of the page. So, you can just use `\paperwidth`. Here's a macro version that allows some adjustment of the width via an optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fullrule}[1][2pt]{%
  \par\nobreak\noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \rule[.5ex]{\paperwidth}{#1}}\par
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1]

\fullrule

\lipsum[2]

\fullrule[.4pt]

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Note that we place the rule inside a zero-width box to avoid any warnings about an overfull `\hbox`.